# Environment variable in MS Access on OneDrive

Tags: vba, ms-access, environment-variables

I have a user who is unable to log into my Access database when the environ("username") function is added to the DB.  The database resides on OneDrive because we need to share a single copy.

There is a module that stores the username function, having the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function UserName() As String
    Dim cn As String
    Dim ls As Long
    Dim res As Long

    cn = String(1024, 0)
    ls = 1024
    res = GetUserName(cn, ls)
    If res <> 0 Then
        UserName = Mid(cn, 1, InStr(cn, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        UserName = ""
    End If
End Function
```

There is a login form through which the username() value is written to a log table.

I am able to log in to the database when it is on OneDrive, but my user cannot.  When he double-clicks it, he is unable to even click the 'enable content' button.  It is just frozen and he has to close access completely.

When I check the log table I can see my login activity with my username, so I know the environment variable is working for me.  My goal is to be able to use the environment variable to identify the current user, store login and store record update activities.

Thank you for any assistance,
LJ

Comment: Happens to only this one user? Is db split? Have you searched this topic in attempt to find resolution? What have you tried?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with 'Enable content', not with code. Code just does not work at all. You need to check how to enable content, https://superuser.com/questions/609592/active-content-security-warning-in-all-files or search for similar questions

Comment: I have tried error handling, specifically 'on error resume next' in the login form.  The user still had an issue and was not able to open the DB and login.  I will review the posted article on how to enable content.  Thank you

Comment: This is an intriguing question. Doing some research.

Comment: I had the user go into Access / Options / Trust center and add the database folder to their trusted locations.  After doing that, the user was able to log into the database without any errors and the environment variable successfully captured his windows name.  Success!

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft warns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446) against opening Access databases on shared document libraries. This includes Sharepoint and OneDrive, even in cases where an Access front-end on a client machine is accessing a split database stored in the document library. They warn that, "multiple copies of the database may get created and some unexpected behaviors may occur." They don't specify what behaviors, but I can guess data corruption for one.

I recommend installing and configuring a [VPN server](https://opensource.com/article/18/6/vpn-alternatives) that supports the L2TP and IPsec protocols, and sharing the back-end (tables only) of the split database in a securely configured public directory.  L2TP and IPsec could resolve the authentication issued you described. Point the Access clients to back-end tables in that directory. It will appear as a shared folder on the LAN.

An alternative is to share the database from a cloud platform, like [JumpCloud](https://jumpcloud.com/pricing?gclid=Cj0KCQjwpdqDBhCSARIsAEUJ0hMGfR2whij6bmWtWYtpjYHm61Qx4T-XBEgkfZap8FWbYX6YDJkSaq0aApFDEALw_wcB&creative=481273877223&keyword=%2Bopenvpn%20%2Bserver&matchtype=b&network=g&device=c&utm_source=GoogleAds-Paid&utm_medium=Paid-Search&utm_term=%2Bopenvpn%20%2Bserver&utm_content=481273877223&utm_campaign=Search_US_Radius&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpdqDBhCSARIsAEUJ0hMGfR2whij6bmWtWYtpjYHm61Qx4T-XBEgkfZap8FWbYX6YDJkSaq0aApFDEALw_wcB) (very affordable), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-desktop/), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/?workspaces-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&workspaces-blogs.sort-order=desc), [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/virtual-desktops), [VMWare Cloud](https://cloud.vmware.com/providers/search-result), or [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/access-server/).

Comment: Yes this is the direction we are going in.  We have had multiple copies of the DB created in OneDrive.  We are a small enough team that we can work around that one at a time, but are going to support more users in the future.  We have an ongoing effort with IT to get all users access to VPN on a LAN and move the DB there, eventually using the split DB.  Thanks for the feedback.